# undefined method for #<#<Class:0x007f05d8ec12d0>:0x007f05d8fa9be8> in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

Hello I am beginner to ruby on rails and I am making a form for taking student's info. I am facing the problem here:

My view code is:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
       <%= form_for(@userinfo)  do |f| %>
         <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
         <%= f.label :name %>
         <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'  %>
         <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
       <% end %>
     </div>
    </div>
```

My controller code is:

```
     def new
       @userinfo= Userinfo.new
     end
```

My routing is:

```
     get 'about' => 'userinfo#new'
```

I am getting the error:  "undefined method `userinfos_path' for #<#:0x007f05d8fa9be8> "

I am beginner to this. How to solve this problem. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your `rake routes` output

Comment: try `get '/about' => 'userinfos#new'`

Comment: @Sontya i have done this but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a route for userinfos.

try adding in your config/routes.rb:

`resources :userinfos`

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it gives you exceptions is you're using `form_for(@userinfo)` simply in your view which intelligently generates form action for you.

Simply, you can specify the form attributes, like 
`form_for(@userinfo, url: '/about/create')`, for more Rails way, you'll need to add `method: :put`

Here's the example:
`ruby
form_for @userinfo, url: '/about/create', method: :put, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }`

Otherwise, @Archie Reyes 's answer works great.